# If Cell Starts with Text String... Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have formula that checks if the cell starts with text "A" returns Pick up "B" for Collect and C for Prepaid.

But it doesn't seems to be working properly

Both A and C returns Prepaid...

`=LOOKUP(LEFT(A1),{"A","B","C"},{"Pick Up","Collect","Prepaid"})`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm not sure [lookup](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/lookup.php) is the right formula for this because of multiple arguments. Maybe [hlookup](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/lookup.php) or [vlookup](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php) but these require you to have tables for values. A simple nested series of [if](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php) does the trick for a small sample size

Try
`=IF(A1="a","pickup",IF(A1="b","collect",IF(A1="c","prepaid","")))`

Now incorporate your `left` argument

`=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="a","pickup",IF(LEFT(A1,1)="b","collect",IF(LEFT(A1,1)="c","prepaid","")))`

Also note your usage of [left](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php), your argument doesn't specify the number of characters, but a set.

---

7/8/15 - Microsoft KB articles for the above mentioned functions. I don't think there's anything *wrong* with `techonthenet`, but I rather link to official sources.

- [lookup](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb)
- [hlookup](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/HLOOKUP-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f)
- [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
- [if](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)
- [left](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)

Comment: Yes `Left` is needed since it's not single character "A" it's more like   A-###, B-###...

Comment: @pnuts it works for me as well except it returns "prepaid" for any value except a or b. Maybe it's supposed to be an array formula?

Answer (score 4):

As of Excel 2019 you could do this.  The "Error" at the end is the default.

```
SWITCH(LEFT(A1,1), "A", "Pick Up", "B", "Collect", "C", "Prepaid", "Error")
```

[Microsoft Excel Switch Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old post, but I found it in searching for a solution to the same problem.  I don't want a nested if-statement, and Switch is apparently newer than the version of Excel I'm using.  I figured out what was going wrong with my code, so I figured I'd share here in case it helps someone else.

I remembered that VLOOKUP requires the source table to be sorted alphabetically/numerically for it to work.  I was initially trying to do this...

```
=LOOKUP(LOWER(LEFT($T$3, 1)),  {"s","l","m"}, {-1,1,0})
```

and it started working when I did this...

```
=LOOKUP(LOWER(LEFT($T$3, 1)),  {"l","m","s"}, {1,0,-1})
```

I was initially thinking the last value might turn out to be a default, so I wanted the zero at the last place.  That doesn't seem to be the behavior anyway, so I just put the possible matches in order, and it worked.

Edit: As a final note, I see that the example in the original post has letters in alphabetical order, but I imagine the real use case might have been different if the error was happening and the letters A, B, and C were just examples.